# python: codingbat no_teen_sum - why my function isn't working as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Below is the code I used for the no_teen_sum and subsequent fixed_teen functions.

The first code is what I submitted - and worked for all test cases:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  # checks if value is a teen then child conditional checks whether
  # fix_teen passes the value, otherwise initialize the value as 0
  if 13 <= a <= 19:
    if fix_teen(a):
      a = a
    else:
      a = 0
  if 13 <= b <= 19:
    if fix_teen(b):
      b = b
    else:
      b = 0
  if 13 <= c <= 19:
    if fix_teen(c):
      c = c
    else:
      c = 0

  return a + b + c
```

And the fix_teen function that is called:

```
def fix_teen(n):
  # checks if n is 15 or 16 but checking if it is found in the set 
  # written this way to be expandable without becoming verbose
  if n in {15, 16}:
    return True
```

However, looking at this I saw a lot of repitition and realized maybe I had misread what the question was asking. It was valid in terms of finding a solution but not as clean as it could be. So I tried to work on an improvement.

Improved code:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    fix_teen(a)
    fix_teen(b)
    fix_teen(c)

    return a + b + c
```

And the modified fix_teen function:

```
def fix_teen(n):

    # checks if n is a teen
    if 13 <= n <= 19:

        # checks if n is 15 or 16 but checking if it is found in the set
        # if True then leave n as it is
        if n in {15, 16}:
            n = n
            return n

        # if it fails then n = 0
        else:
            n = 0
            return n

    # if n is not in the teens return it as is
    return n
```

The issue I am having for example a test case of (1, 2, 18) is that it returns 21. It should return 3. I tried putting print statements in between each 'fix_teen' call in the main function to see what value it had for a, b, c and it just left them as is (1, 2, 18) rather than (1, 2, 0)

The weird part is if I called fixed_teen(18) independently it returns 0.

Comment: Check your no_teen_sum(a, b, c) function

You are returning a + b + c (which is literally what gets passed to the function)! You should make a = fix_teen(a), b = fix_teen(b), c = fix_teen(c) and then return a + b + c

Comment: Doh! Makes so much sense now. I was returning the value but it wasn't picked up anywhere in the no_teen_sum function. Thank you. If you want the points for solution you can answer the question and I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your no_teen_sum(a, b, c) function is returning a + b + c (which is literally what gets passed to the function)! You should make a, b and c equal to the result from the fix_teen function to get the desired result!

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    a = fix_teen(a)
    b = fix_teen(b)
    c = fix_teen(c)

    return a + b + c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    return print(fix_teen(a) + fix_teen(b) + fix_teen(c))

def fix_teen(n):
    if n in (13, 14, 17, 18, 19):
        return 0
    return n

no_teen_sum(1, 2, 3)
no_teen_sum(2, 13, 1)
no_teen_sum(2, 1, 14)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Returning the result of print means that you are always returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  
  teens = [13, 14, 17, 18, 19]
  nums = [a,b,c]
  sum = 0
  
  for num in nums:
    if num in teens:
      sum += 0
    else:
      sum += num
      
  return sum
```

This uses a single for loop to iterate through nums. The check for teens is done in the if block and changed to zero only if encountered.

If you are using decomposition with two functions the fix_teen method can be shortened as follows. Since 15,16 return as is, you do not need to include them in the check.

```
def fix_teen(n):
  
  teens = [13, 14, 17, 18, 19]

  if n in teens:
    return 0
  else:
    return n
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  return fix_teen(a) + fix_teen(b) + fix_teen(c)

def fix_teen(n):
     teen = [13, 14, 17, 18, 19]
     if n in teen :
        return 0
     else:
        return n
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. You should also sorround you code with code fences ```.